# Starting Mule 4.4.0 as a linux service

Tags: mule, mule4

According to Mule documentation, the recommended way to install Mule as a service is to use the Java Service Wrapper by running:

```
$MULE_HOME/bin/mule install
```

After running the command, Mule just runs in the foreground. The same thing happens if I run:

```
$MULE_HOME/bin/mule remove
```

Using systemctl to start/stop

```
systemctl mule start
systemctl mule stop
```

returns the message "mule.service could not be found." Does this feature only work with the enterprise version? The documentation does not specify if this works with the community edition.

Here are links to the documentation I used:

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Starting-mule-as-a-service-on-linux

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/starting-and-stopping-mule-esb#start-mule-as-a-linuxunix-daemon

Comment: if there is an error message you should add it verbatim to your question, along with the exact command used. Documentation links will also be appreciated as reference to understand what you found. The output of the other commands that you mentioned should be also added.

Comment: The exact commands I used are in the question, and there are no error messages. As stated in the question, mule just starts normally.

Comment: Which configuration changes from the article did you implement? What distribution and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: According to the documentation running `$MULE_HOME/bin/mule install` should install mule as a service, but when I execute this command, it just runs mule in the foreground as if I executed `$MULE_HOME/bin/mule.` There doesn't seem to be any service setup. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: The KB you shared article mentions additional steps after that. Did you follow them?

Comment: Actually those steps are to manually installing mule as a service and is not recommended. Like the article says, the recommended way is to run `$MULE_HOME/bin/mule install` but as I mentioned, it does not install the service.